# How to add notifications using react-native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am doing this project on snack expo online and not local level.
I am having a tough-time trying to add the notifications feature for the app. I am continuously getting errors for the same .The notifications should be such which are sent according to the date and for different items and their events. It's basically not working.

I tried searching many documentations and tutorials online but all of then either use function App() or .According to my project I have App.js as a class with already existing stack navigation. I am relatively new so don't know much about all of this but how can I send notifications to the user (currently in expo go) according to date. I also tried using firebase cloud-messaging but I am not able to retrieve the token and getting the error :

```
_firebase.default.messaging.requestPermission is not a function
```

I have been trying from a long time using various documentations but I am not able to do so.
I basically am trying to get a way to send notifications. I have some different screen's such as home.js , app.js and navigations screen: navigate.js with pre-existing stack navigation.
How should I implement the notification feature?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Expo push notifications using their documentation here: [Expo Push Notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/). See the minimal working example [here](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/#add-a-minimal-working-example) to receive and send a push notification using their push service.